# Using Schwarz reflection principle

Tags: complex-analysis

There is a slit plane $\mathbb{C}-(-\infty,0]$ and the cone inside it $C=\{z:\mid z\mid>0,arg(z)\in(\alpha,\beta)\}$. I need to show that if $f$ is holomorphic in $C$, real on $\bar C$, and extends continuously to $\bar C$, we can extend $f$ to $\mathbb{C}-(-\infty,0]$.

In order to use the reflection principle, the book says that we can observe that upto rotation by $\alpha$ or $\beta$, it has the same setup as reflection principle. But I can't really see this either algebraically or geometrically. Can you please explain how this works? I understand the Schwarz reflection principle, but don't know how to change the variable of the function to apply it. I would appreciate any insight of this.

Comment: Suppose we start with the sector $C(0, \alpha) = \{z: |z| > 0 \land 0 < \arg z < \alpha\}$. The idea is that we can construct an analytic function on $C(0, 2 \alpha)$, then on $C(0, 4 \alpha)$, and so on, but when we complete one full circle, we may obtain a different branch of the multivalued function, thus we need to introduce a branch cut.

Comment: I understand everything except the part about branch. Reading your comment, I can imagine, if, say, $\alpha>0$ and $\beta<0$, then we can extend the sector $0\leq\theta<\alpha$ to $0\leq\theta<\pi$ and the sector $\beta<\theta\leq 0$ to $-\pi<\theta\leq 0$ but the question now is, if I can combine these two continuation.

Comment: Or, rather, I think I can use the full $0\leq\theta<\alpha+\beta$ and repeatedly use the schwarz lemma, and in the case it pasts full circle, I can use the different branch of logarithm to make it continuous

Comment: But now the question is, in order to use Schwarz reflection lemma, I can only have the domain less than 180 degrees